# Customising the appearance of GTK widgets

Tags: widget, styles, gtk

I wish to create custom widgets using GTK+. For example I would like to create a checkbox that instead of a tick it displays an icon or gtk image that i have created. I have read the styling documentation, but it doesn't seem to allow you to change the widget.

Is it best to create a new widget or can i just customise the GTKCheckButton style?

Answer (score 0):

A [GtkCssProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.7/GtkCssProvider.html) allows basic styling of widgets, if you need anything fancy (like special shaped windows) you will need to implement / derive your own.